# How to force valueUpdate (knockoutJS) with spinner input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, spinner

I have a spinner with the following HTML:

```
<input id="infoX"  data-bind="spinner: infoXpos, spinnerOptions: { min: -50, max: 50 }, valueUpdate: ['propertychange','input']"  />
```

However the valueUpdate doesn´t seem to work until I change focus.
Is there any other way to force the update so that each time the spinner buttons are hit, "infoXpos" is updated?

Below is my bindingHandler:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.spinner = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().spinnerOptions || {};

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "spinchange", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).spinner("value"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).spinner("destroy");
        });

        $(element).spinner(options);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).spinner("value");

        if (value !== current) {
            $(element).spinner("value", value);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems just posting to SO has a great effect on my problem solving. ;)

The solution is very simple. I changed the event hander to respond on "spinstop" rather than "spin change".

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "spinstop", function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable($(element).spinner("value"));
    });
```

That made it.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/m6ztnqxc/